# open and save an excel 2003 sheet every ten minutes

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file, cmd

I am using excel 2003.
My requirement is to open and save an excel sheet  every ten minutes.

My Sheet uses a ODBC connection to get data and it refreshes every time when it opens.

I created a scheduled task  to run a bat file which calls a VB script which will open the excel sheet  and save it before closing it.

Bat file

```
C:\SaveExcel.vbs C:\MySheet.xls
Exit
```

VB Script:

```
    Dim args, objExcel
    Set args = WScript.Arguments
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Workbooks.Open args(0)
    objExcel.Visible = True
    objExcel.Workbooks.Open "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\Library\Analysis\FUNCRES.XLA"
    objExcel.Addins("Analysis Toolpak").Installed = True
    objExcel.Addins("Analysis ToolPak - VBA").Installed = True

    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    WScript.Sleep 10000  ' Waiting  as refresh may take upto ten seconds
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(0)
    objExcel.Quit
```

The problem with the above is the addin "Analysis Toolpak' is not loaded ,hence most of  the formulas are not working when i open the sheet using above VB.

The addins works if i open via CMD.

```
CMD>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\EXCEL.EXE" "C:\MySheet.xls"
```

I never woked with VB , is there a way to merge the cmd and vb to meet my requirement?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to load `AddIns("Analysis ToolPak - VBA").Installed = True`  also ?

Answer (score 1):

Try loading the `Analysis ToolPak - VBA` also.  That could cause the problems you see...

```
AddIns("Analysis ToolPak - VBA").Installed = True
```

Comment: What version of excel do you have?

Comment: Sorry i didn't mention. I am using Excel 2003

Comment: If you look at http://forums.techguy.org/business-applications/616829-solved-analysis-tool-pak-functions.html     about half way down it says `Oh, and you could try unloading it, closing Excel, reopening Excel, then loading the add-in again. 
`

Comment: Jim , the addin works perfectly when i open the sheet directly or by cmd. It doesn't work  with VB.

Comment: It sounds like only part of it is loading though and 2003 has a lot of those kinds of problem....

Comment: What version of Windows do you have?

Comment: @ Jim Do you have any other approach in mind ? I just need to open a sheet with addins then save it and close.